# Custom folding citations in AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, code-folding, reftex-mode

By default, only `\cite` is folded by AUCTeX. If you want other citation commands to be folded as well, you have to add them to `LaTeX-fold-macro-spec-list` manually. For example, with `(push '("[nc]" ("nocite")) LaTeX-fold-macro-spec-list)`, I tell AUCTEX to fold the command `\nocite` and display "[nc]". If you want only the contents in parentheses to be shown but not the command (as it is done with sections or italics), you can replace "[nc]" by "{1}". In this case, only the citation key is displayed.

Now I have two specific cases which make me despair:

1. I'd like to have `\citealias` folded as specified in `\defcitealias` in my .tex-file. For example, if I define `\defcitealias{key}{In December}`, `\citealias{key}` should fold into "In December".
2. I'm trying to have `\parencite` folded to "(author, year, page)" as specified in the .bib-file. For example, if "key" is the citation key for "examplearticle", which is specified in the .bib-file as

   ```
   @article{examplearticle,
   title = {example title},
   author = {Gentzen, Gerhard},
   date = {1935-12}, ...}
   ```

AUCTeX should fold `\parencite[20]{example}` and display "(Gentzen, 1935, p. 20)".

I'm quite new to elisp and this is simply too big of a task for me. Can anyone of you help me out?